# Is there a way to print class object data based on user input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code to generate information on a certain subject when user input is given. The final goal is to make a version of the Pokedex, with all 800+ Pokemon identified. I currently have a class set up with the ability to add new Pokemon to it with ease. The problem lies in where I try to call information about each Pokemon.

```
class pokemon:
    def __init__(self, id_num, name):
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.name = name
    def information(self):
        print(__name__.id_num)

Bulbasaur = pokemon("001", "Bulbasaur")

print("What Pokemon are you looking for today?")
poke = input()
pokemon.information(poke)
```

This is a trimmed version of the full class I used. What I wanted it to do was print the ID number of the Pokemon's name when the user inputs the name. In this example, typing "Bulbasaur" would have outputted "001". However, I receive this error:

```
C:\--->pokedex.py
What Pokemon are you looking for today?
Bulbasaur
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\---\pokedex.py", line 13, in <module>
    pokemon.information(poke)
  File "C:\---\pokedex.py", line 7, in information
    print(__name__.id_num)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id_num'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I want to avoid using `if poke = "Bulbasaur": print(Bulbasaur.id_num)` since I would need to do that for every Pokemon.

Comment: Replace `print(__name__.id_num)` by `print(self.id_num)`

Comment: Create a mapping from names to Pokemon objects. Objects don't inherently have a "name" and have no knowledge of the variables that happen to be referring to it at any given moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of a method of the object you are interested in, you can just print `id_num`.